A new inequality for the Gamma function?
Recently, in Proposition 13 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2412.17475 the following inequality about the Gamma function $\Gamma$ was proven.

Let $x,y> 0$. Then
$$
\Bigg(\frac{x \cdot\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(y+\frac{y}{x})}\Bigg)^x\Bigg(\frac{y \cdot \Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x+\frac{x}{y})}\Bigg)^y \le 1,
$$
and equality holds if and only if $x=y$.

Is this inequality known (in rewritten form)?
The proof in the above reference involves an entropy maximization problem. Is there a proof involving other known inequalities for the Gamma function?
